# Issue with draw a path through markers

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app it's possibile to insert markers with touch and then it's possible to calculate the path through these markers with subsequent HTTP requests.

The issue is that very often the first markers is skipped and between the last two markers is drawn a segment **too**.

Here's the code:

```
public class MultipleTracksDrawer extends AbstractDrawer {

    private static final String TAG_LOG = MultipleTracksAsyncTask.class.getName();

    private boolean flag = false;

    void draw() {

        for(int i = 0; i < markers.size() - 1; i++) {

            Marker firstMarker = markers.get(i);
            Marker secondMarker = markers.get(i + 1);
            //I extract latitude and longitude from the markers
            LatLng firstLatLng = new LatLng(firstMarker.getPosition().latitude,      firstMarker.getPosition().longitude);
            LatLng secondLatLng = new LatLng(secondMarker.getPosition().latitude, secondMarker.getPosition().longitude);

            //Url for the request
            String URL = Utilities.getInstance().makeURL(firstLatLng.latitude, firstLatLng.longitude,
                secondLatLng.latitude, secondLatLng.longitude, travelMode);

            //At the end of the markers list i set the flag as true for draw the path
            if(i == markers.size() - 2) {
                flag = true;
            }

            MultipleTracksAsyncTask multipleTracksAsyncTask = new MultipleTracksAsyncTask(URL);
            multipleTracksAsyncTask.execute();
        }
    }

    private class MultipleTracksAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        private ProgressDialog mDialog;
        private String URL;

        public MultipleTracksAsyncTask(String URL) {
            this.URL = URL;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", true);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(mDialog != null) {
                if(mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            if(result != null) {
                parseJSON(result);
                //I draw the path only if the flag is true
                if(flag) {
                    drawPath();
                }
            }
        }

        public String doInBackground(Void... param) {
            JSONRequest jParser = new JSONRequest();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL,connectionTimeout,dataTimeout);
            return json;
        }
    }

    private void parseJSON(String result) {
        try {
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            //I get "routes" array
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray legsArray = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject legsObject = legsArray.getJSONObject(0);
            //I get distance and duration of the path
            JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject duration = legsObject.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            //Decoding
            model.getMarkersTrack().addAll(Utilities.getInstance().decodePoly(encodedString));

            mTrackDistance += distance.getInt("value");
            mTrackDuration += duration.getInt("value");
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "The path is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void drawPath() {

        for(int i = 0; i < model.getMarkersTrack().size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLng src = model.getMarkersTrack().get(i);
            LatLng dest = model.getMarkersTrack().get(i + 1);
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude,  dest.longitude))
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
            Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            //I save the polylines 
            model.getTrackPolylines().add(polyline);
        }
    }
}
```

I put here the code for the HTTP request too:

```
public class JSONRequest {

    private InputStream is = null;
    private String json = "";

    /**
     * Method that makes the HTTP request
     *
     * @param url URL of the HTTP request
     * @param connectionTimeout timeout for the connection
     * @param dataTimeout timeout for the download
     * @return
     */
    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url, int connectionTimeout, int dataTimeout) {

        try {
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,connectionTimeout);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, dataTimeout);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            //GET request
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            //I get the response
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //I read the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Here's a picture: http://imageshack.com/a/img835/504/m0fc.png

UPDATE:

Problem fixed!

Now i create a new String URL in the draw() method of MultipleTracksDrawer class and i give it to the AsyncTask (as input parameter). In this way it works. I edited the code.

Comment: is it possible that you could show us some image sample?

Comment: I have no enough reputation :( But you can imagine the path drawn through the markers except from first to second AND a segment is added between the last two markers. I have no idea why -.-

Comment: upload it on some website and pass the link.. sorry Im bad on that(Imagining)..

Comment: I think you should pass new DefaultHttpClient Object each time you are requesting the REST api's of google because it's not possible to request more than once with single HttpClient.So may be the last result is shown to you.

Comment: I added a image and the code for the HTTP request in the question. Pankaj, in the code above, i create and start a new AsyncTask for each pair of markers in the list. The AsyncTask in turn creates a new class for the HTTP request. So every time a new DefaultHttpClient Object is created.

Comment: I want to clarify that sometimes works well!